# Aeroplane - prevent rotation outside limits, but allow turning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I have an aeroplane object that rotates using Input.GetAxis input. It's limited to a 100degree range of motion on both z and y axes:

```cs
if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 50 || transform.eulerAngles.z > 310) {
  transform.Rotate(0f, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
}
if (transform.eulerAngles.y < 50 || transform.eulerAngles.y > 310) {
  transform.Rotate(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0f, 0f);
}
```

The plane is propelled forward by pressing a button, and `forward` is the direction the plane is facing:

```cs
transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed;
```

This doesn't behave as I'd like. When the plane reaches the limit of the rotation (e.g. transform.eulerAngles.z == 50), the plane no longer moves in an 'arc', as in, `forward` is not a straight line. When it reaches the limit, the plane just moves in a straight line. I'd like it to continue to arc, just not beyond the rotation limit. I hope that makes sense? Does anyone have any tips on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite believe how obvious the solution was... Of course, I don't want the y axis to stop rotating. Here's my solution:

```cs
float getHorizontal;
float getVertical;

if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 50 || transform.eulerAngles.z > 310) {
  getHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
} else {
  getHorizontal = 0f;
}

if (transform.eulerAngles.x < 50 || transform.eulerAngles.x > 310) {
  getVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
} else {
  getVertical = 0f;
}

transform.Rotate(getVertical, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), -getHorizontal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are comparing the rotated angle with the euler angles. So, when you arrive to 50 degrees it is not posible to rotate more.

You have to compare the rotation with the forward vector and limit this rotation to 50 degrees

Comment: Hi @Jordi, thank you for your reply. Geometry is definitely not my strongest area, so I have to think about this... am I correct in thinking I will have to change the `transform.position =` to  `transform.forward...` plus or minus the rotated angle? (sorry, not sure what the difference between rotated angle and Euler angle is, I thought they were the same thing)

Comment: Instead of comparing with euler angles that are absolute world angles of rotation, you have to compare the new direction given by the input getAxis with the forward direction your plane is flying currently. If this rotation is greater than 50 degrees then you have to limit it